# Can not find a specific group in MS Windows 2008

Tags: windows-server-2008, active-directory, ad-certificate-services, pki

In a MS-Win 2008 SP2 I am trying to find the group CERTSVC_DCOM_ACCESS.
I followed this link [Error in MS-CA request](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/927066) instructions but I can not seem to find that group.
Where it? Does it have a different name?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

They made the name a little more friendly these days, which may be why you couldn't find it.

It's created as a local group, so look in the local users/groups management tools; if your CA is a DC it'll be a Domain Local group instead.

[image: group]

Comment: Correct. I also found by googling, that the name changed.But the problem is that this group is NOT visible in the `Groups` panel.If I right click a domain user e.g. the Administrator and go to the `Member of` tab, if I search through the groups, the `Certificate Service DCOM` you mention is part of the list and the administrator can be added.But the problem is that this group per se is not present in the groups panel.The reason I am looking into this, is because it might be the cause of this http://serverfault.com/questions/312097/question-on-certutil problem I have